# Django, manager no reconoce mi CustomUser

Tags: django, django-models

A la hora de tratar mi manager personalizado django no reconoce mi AUTH_USER_MODEL, nose que le pasa pero no puedo completar mi manager, no se si el problema es que no reconoce mi modelo o es que no instancia bien, nose, aqui el codigo:

No se por que motivo pasa esto , creo que hay un problema con mi usuario perzonalizado, de alguna forma no sabe que esta establecido como usuario perzonalizado o algo asi

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
#from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager (tambien intente importarlo de base_user)

class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)###AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA####
        user = set_password(password)           ###no tiene la funcion model()###
        user.save()                             ### y no puedo finalizar mi clase ya que me lanza error###
                                                ###tampoco puedo utilizar set_password obviamente###
```

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Accounts',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Accounts.CustomUser'
```

Mi settings.py no tiene ningun fallo , ni le falta ningun dato

models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Datos que se piden a los usuarios
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=45)
    last_name = models.CharField('Apellidos', max_length=120)
    age = models.IntegerField('Edad')
    phone_number = models.CharField('Numero de telefono', max_length=9)
    # Tipo de usuario
    is_admin_page = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin_partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Datos que se asignan automaticamente
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Manager personalizado
    #objects = CustomManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'phone_number']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name + " " + self.email
```

Alomejor el problema esta en AbstractBaseuser?, nose pero no conecta bien

Answer (score 0):

nose por que , pero he copiado y pegado esto y ahora si ha funcionado, si alguien sabe por que, sientete libre de decirlo por que yo no tengo ni idea:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

Te explico por que sucede esto, cuando quieres extender el modelo de usuario de Django tienes dos opciones, extender la clase AbstractUser o la clase AbstractBaseUser. Django por defecto utiliza la clase AbstractUser la cual contiene un manager por defecto y esta clase a su vez extiende defecto, esto lo puedes observar acá: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L358

Ahora, como estas utilizando la otra implementación con el AbstractBaseUser si observas en el código aquí: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L48

Podrás notar que no tienen ningún manager por defecto, por lo que a fuerza se requiere su implementación, en este caso tu modelo CustomUser debe de incluir el manager que pusiste en la ultima respuesta. Para este caso seria:

```
objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Y básicamente es por esto que tuviste que agregar el manager.

Espero esta respuesta de haya sido de ayuda. Saludos.